# How to handle conditional sub-category in AngularJS product gallery

Tags: angularjs

Just starting out learning AngularJS and decided to mock up a basic product gallery using what I've learned so far and I've hit a roadblock. Currently I have a simple product gallery with 3 templates(category listing, products in category listing and product overview). What I would like to do is set up some sort of conditional, where if the products in a selected category have a sub-category, it displays a list of sub-categories using the `category-list` template. If they don't have a sub-category it just goes straight to the `product-list` template.

I have [created this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oRJcsv36eSW0dLP1ZX0r) showing where I am at so far.

In the above example, if someone clicks on "Cars" I want it to then show a listing of sub-categories using the `category-list` template. So when you click "Cars" it would take you to a screen with 2 buttons: `4-door` and `2-door`. Clicking on one of those buttons would then show you the products from those sub-categories using the `product-list` template. However, if you were to click on "Trucks" from the initial screen, it would just take you directly to the `product-list` template since the trucks don't have sub-categories.

Here is my category-list template:

```
<section id="categories" ng-hide="productsVisible">
    <div ng-repeat="product in vm.products" class="category">
        <div ng-click="vm.selectCategory(product); showProducts();">
            <button>{{product.category}}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And here is my product-list template:

```
<section id="products" ng-show="productsVisible">
    <div ng-repeat="product in vm.selectedCategory.items" class="product">
        <a href ng-click="vm.selectProduct(product); showResults();">{{product.name}}</a>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1sdPJvRHGGKOqUq515qv)

Basically, you need to extend the `selectCategory` method by grouping the sub-categories and checking whether we're about to enter this sub-category in subsequent click. Like this:

```
vm.selectCategory = function(category) {
  var subCats = [],
      map = {};

  if (category.items && !category.items[0].subCategory){
    vm.selectedCategory = category;
    vm.inSubCat = true;
    return;
  }

  vm.inSubCat = !category.items;
  if (category.items) category.items.forEach(function(e){
    if (!map[e.subCategory]) subCats.push({category: e.subCategory, name: category.category});
    map[e.subCategory] = true;
  });
  vm.products = subCats;

  if (vm.inSubCat) vm.selectedCategory = {items: vm.data.filter(function(c){
    return c.category == category.name;
  })[0].items.filter(function(p){
    return p.subCategory == category.category;
  }) };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest your data model could use some work, and put all the products in a single array with categories and subcategories as properties.  However, you can get what you want with this change to the products-list.html.

```html
<div ng-show="vm.selectedCategory.category=='Cars'">
<input type="radio" ng-model="subcategory" value="2-Door">Coupe
<input type="radio" ng-model="subcategory" value="4-Door">Sedan
</div>
 
<section id="products" ng-show="productsVisible">
 <div ng-repeat="product in vm.selectedCategory.items" class="product">
  <a ng-show="product.subCategory===subcategory" href ng-click="vm.selectProduct(product); showResults();">{{product.name}}</a>
 </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to refactor the code in two possible ways:

a) Try to remove lines from controller that control the view (the process of displaying different directives) and use events in directives

b) Control your view by using ng-show and ng-hide directives that will show or hide some part of your code.